# How can I set the values of an OptionBox with another list using setOptionBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, drop-down-menu, tkinter

I am currently creating a GUI using `appJar`:

```
from appJar import gui

listOne = ["first", "set", "of", "values"]
listTwo = ["second", "set", "of", "values"]

def reset(reset):
    app.setOptionBox("optionBoxTwo", listTwo)

app=gui()

app.addOptionBox("optionBoxOne", ["foo", "bar"])
app.setOptionBoxChangeFunction("optionBoxOne", reset)

app.addOptionBox("optionBoxTwo", listOne)

app.go()
```

I have `optionBoxOne`, which contents are irrelevant at this stage. When the selection of this option box is changed, it executes `reset` function. Expected, is to change the values of `optionBoxTwo` to `listTwo`. This however, does not work and I am returned with the following error:

```
Warning - Invalid selection option: ['second', 'set', 'of', 'values']
```

This suggests I can only change the currently displayed value, rather than the values to be displayed. For example if I change the `reset` function to this:

```
def reset(reset):
    app.setOptionBox("optionBoxTwo", "values")
```

Then the function will execute as expected. Upon changing the value of `optionBoxOne`, the currently displayed value of `optionBoxTwo` changes to `"values"`.

I would like to change the values to be displayed. I have tried using a dictionary as the parameter when adding the option box:

```
app.addOptionBox("optionBoxOne", {"listOne" : ["foo", "bar"], "listTwo" : ["something"]})
```

And then in the function, I state the key of the list I would like to display:

```
def reset(reset):
    app.setOptionBox("optionBoxTwo", listTwo)
```

This however, does not work as expected. Instead, the values that are displayed in the option box are simply the keys of the dictionary only.

How can I change the values to be displayed in an option box, in this manner? I have found one workaround and that's to remove the option box and then re-add it with the desired list:

```
def reset(reset):
    app.removeOptionBox("optionBoxTwo")
    app.addOptionBox("optionBoxTwo", listTwo)
```

Although this seems a bit cheap and unpythonic. But it does achieve desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, it seems like a for loop might solve your issue.  Maybe try something like this.

```
def reset(reset):
    for val in listTwo:
        app.setOptionBox("optionBoxTwo", val)
```

This should iterate through all the values in your list and call `app.setOptionBox` for each one.

Comment: Unfortunately the outcome is not as expected. This only sets the final element of `listTwo` to `optionBoxTwo`. Note that when trying to set `second` to `optionBoxTwo` this returned an error as `"second"` does not exist in `optionBoxTwo`.